# System.TypeLoadException in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error

I am getting a 'System.TypeLoadException' that is occuring in System.Windows.Forms.dll.  Here is the remainder of the error message.

> Additional information: Could not load type 'DataTeamMailerCSharp.NewReport' from assembly 'DataTeamMailerCSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method '.ctor' has no implementation (no RVA).

Here is the class this is happening in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataTeamMailerCSharp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new mainGUI());
        }
    }
}
```

The error is occuring here:

```
Application.Run(new mainGUI());
```

In response to the comment, I did recently change this in one of my classes.  I am attemptin XML Serialization, and in the parameterless constructor it was telling me that it needed a body or exter, partial, and something else.  Here is the class code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataTeamMailerCSharp
{
    [Serializable] class NewPerson
    {
        public string personName { get; set; }
        public string personEmail { get; set; }
        public string personReports { get; set; }

        public NewPerson(string name, string email, string reports)
        {
            personName = name;
            personEmail = email;
            personReports = reports;
        }

        private extern NewPerson();
    }
}
```

Could it be be `private extern NewPerson();` that is causing this now?

Comment: the error isn't actually being thrown from where you state but actually perhaps instead of the mainGUI. It is inrelation to a 3rd party assembly you are using/calling called DataTeamMailerCSharp and the problem lays in there and how you are trying to use it.

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `DataTeamMailerCSharp.NewReport`?

Comment: Here is NewPerson, the constructors are nearly the same aside from the parameters.

Comment: any reason for using extern?!

Comment: When I change 'private extern NewPerson();' to 'public NewPerson();' I get a new error: 'DataTeamMailerCSharp.NewPerson.NewPerson()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial'

Comment: Again, I'm trying to make sure I have a parameter-less constructor for the serialization, but I feel that I am implementing it wrong.

Comment: paste this and see public NewPerson(){}...*sign* curly braces...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are serializing/deserializing with `XmlSerializer`, you NEED a public, parameterless default constructor. Add one...

```
namespace DataTeamMailerCSharp
{
    [Serializable] 
    public class NewPerson
    {
        public string personName { get; set; }
        public string personEmail { get; set; }
        public string personReports { get; set; }

        public NewPerson(string name, string email, string reports)
        {
            personName = name;
            personEmail = email;
            personReports = reports;
        }

        public NewPerson() { } // for serialization

        // private extern NewPerson(); -- not needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That resolved that issue, now on to the next one.  I have more of a VB background than C#, and I am finding it is a lot more...particular.  I really appreciate it.